# How do I create a working JAR file once I build JUnit5 from source?

Tags: java, gradle, junit5, gradlew

I recently started learning about unit tests and heard about JUnit testing. I wanted to use Unit5 with my main editor (Neovim) and I looked up some tutorials for JUnit5, but most of them were about how to get it working in Eclipse or IntelliJ.

---

As a side note, I had managed to get JUnit4 quite easily, simply by downloading the zip from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/junit/files/junit/4.10/), putting it in my ~/Library/Java/JUnit directory, and adding the following line to my ~/.zprofile to add JUnit4 to my CLASSPATH environment variable.

```sh
export CLASSPATH="/Users/rahulhegde/Library/Java/JUnit/junit4.10/junit-4.10.jar"
```

I then ran the following command to ensure JUnit4 was installed correctly

```sh
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore junit.tests.AllTests
```

which had the following output

```
JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: org.junit.tests.AllTests

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)
```

I could send the contents of the jar file, but it's pretty long so if someone asks I'll send it.

---

Anyway, I tried to follow the same procedure with JUnit5, but I didn't get very far since I didn't know how to make it into a jar file properly.

I figured I could build JUnit5 from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5) that was liked from their [website](https://junit.org/junit5/) so I went ahead and downloaded their [5.8.2 release](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/releases/tag/r5.8.2) and put it in my ~/Library/Java/JUnit directory (Note: I'm using MacOS with an M1 chip).

Then I ran the following commands

```sh
cd junit5-r5.8.2
cd buildSrc
../gradlew tasks
../gradlew clean assemble
```

this command gave me a warning:

```
Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
warning: ATTENTION!

-XXLanguage:+DisableCompatibilityModeForNewInference

This mode is not recommended for production use,
as no stability/compatibility guarantees are given on
compiler or generated code. Use it at your own risk!
```

but the build succeeded, so I continued

```sh
../gradlew testClasses
../gradlew buildNeeded
../gradlew check
../gradlew test
../gradlew jar
cd build/libs
jar tf buildSrc.jar >> jarcontents.txt
```

(I can send jar contents.txt if someone asks)
now at this point, I assumed that buildSrc.jar was the jar file that I was looking for, and added it to my class path environment variable

```sh
vim ~/.zprofile
```

I added this line

```sh
CLASSPATH="/Users/rahulhegde/Library/Java/JUnit/junit5-r5.8.2/buildSrc/build/libs/buildSrc.jar:${CLASSPATH}"
```

From here I ran `source ~/.zprofile` to apply the environment variable updates,
and then I attempted to run `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` but it still output `JUnit version 4.10`.

So this begs the question -- how does one correctly build from source for JUnit5?

Comment: Even if you are editing Java code in Nvim, aren't you still using Maven/Gradle for building and dependency management? (If not, why not?) Therefore, you would also use it for executing tests, not run a standalone Junit jar

Comment: I don’t think you want to build JUnit 5 yourself. You just want to run in using Jar files instead of downloading it through Maven or Gradle. Have a look at the following section in the user guide: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher